# WSS - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET [paraview-web]

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, paraview

I'm trying to run paraview web and I'm using Apache HTTPS server as a proxy server......

I'm getting the following error, I was unable to open a secure websocket over Apache HTTPS. Here is the apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\SSL\apache.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\SSL\apache.key"

    ServerName MYAPACHE-SERVER
    ServerAdmin admin@MYAPPACHE-SERVER
    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\ParaView 4.1.0\share\paraview-4.1\www"
    ErrorLog "logs/pv-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/pv-access_log" common


    <Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\ParaView 4.1.0\share\paraview-4.1\www" >
       SSLRequireSSL On
       SSLVerifyClient optional
       SSLVerifyDepth 1
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire
     </Location>

    # Turn on the rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    # This is the path the mapping file Jetty creates
    RewriteMap session-to-port "txt:C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonLauncher\mapping\proxy.txt"

    # This is the rewrite condition. Look for anything with a sessionId= in the query part of the URL and capture the value to use below.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^sessionId=(.*)$ [NC]

    # This does the rewrite using the mapping file and the sessionId
    RewriteRule    ^/proxy.*$  ws://${session-to-port:%1}/ws  [P]


    <Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\ParaView 4.1.0\share\paraview-4.1\www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /apps http://localhost:9000/apps 
    ProxyPassReverse /apps http://localhost:9000/apps

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /lib http://localhost:9000/lib 
    ProxyPassReverse /lib http://localhost:9000/lib

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /paraview http://localhost:9000/paraview 
    ProxyPassReverse /paraview http://localhost:9000/paraview


    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /ext http://localhost:9000/ext 
    ProxyPassReverse /ext http://localhost:9000/ext

    ProxyRequests off 
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8181/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8181/

</VirtualHost>
```

I configured paraview web to keep the session url as following:

```
"sessionURL" : "wss://${host}:${port}/proxy?sessionId=${id}"
```

**Apache server version: 2.4.12**

**Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2**

**Paraview-web: 4.1**

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't ..... I will keep you notified If I got it solved